# Django URL converters for date/time values

Tags: python, django, datetime, url

I'm trying to use the URL converters built into Django to convert a date time string in the URL into a date object in my views.

They work as expected if I enter the URL manually, but trying to generate a URL for it cannot find a match.

My converters are simple:

```py
from django.utils.timezone import datetime
from datetime import time

class DateConverter:
    regex = '[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}'

    def to_python(self,value):
        return datetime.strptime(value,"%Y-%m-%d")

    def to_url(self,value):
        return value.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")

class TimeConverter:
    regex = '[0-9]{4}'

    def to_python(self,value):
        t = datetime.strptime(value,"%H%M")
        return time(t.hour,t.minute)

    def to_url(self,value):
        return value.strftime("%H%M")
```

In my template I have some nested loops that are cycling through available time slots where I call `url` for each combination of time slots:

```
 <a href="{% url 'club_boats:trip_booking' trip_date slot.slot.start_time slot.slot.end_time boat.boat.pk %}">Join</a>
```

My `urls.py` file is:

```py
from django.urls import path, register_converter

from . import converters, views

register_converter(converters.DateConverter, 'date')
register_converter(converters.TimeConverter,'time')

urlpatterns = [
    path('<int:boat_id>',views.detail,name='detail'),
    path('<date:trip_date>/',views.day_view,name='day_view'),
    path('<date:trip_date>/<time:trip_start_time>/<time:trip_end_time>/<int:boat>/',views.trip_booking,name='trip_booking'),
    path('', views.day_view, name='day_view')
]
```

I've confirmed that the data types match what it's expecting (time, datetime, etc...) but the reverse conversion doesn't seem to be happening.

When I try to load the tempalte that contains the above `url` call I get a NoReverseMatch error:

```
Reverse for 'trip_booking' with arguments '(datetime.datetime(2019, 7, 1, 0, 0), datetime.time(9, 0), datetime.time(12, 30), 1)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['club_boats/(?P<trip_date>[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2})\\/(?P<trip_start_time>[0-9]{4})\\/(?P<trip_end_time>[0-9]{4})\\/(?P<boat>[0-9]+)\\/$']
```

It's obviously seeing the pattern, but something is missing.

Comment: What if you use named parameters, like `{% url 'club_boats:trip_booking' trip_date=trip_date trip_start_time=slot.slot.start_time ... %}'`?

Comment: Same error as before; now it just says "reverse with keyword arguments ..." with a dict rather than just listing the parameters like before